# How to reduce CPU usage on ffmpeg when recording screen (Mac)

Tags: macos, ffmpeg

I am trying to record my screen using ffmpeg, but the CPU usage grows A LOT, it gets to 85% of CPU and 20 threads... after 1 hour recording it is impossible to use the computer.

I've tried to set `threads=2` to reduce the 20 (I can see the threads on the Activity Monitor) but it didn't work at all..

This is the command I am using:

```
ffmpeg -threads 2 -f avfoundation -i 1 -capture_cursor 1 -capture_mouse_clicks 1 -video_size 2560x1600 -b:v 2M -maxrate 2M -bufsize 1.5M -tune zerolatency -crf 17 -preset ultrafast -pix_fmt yuv420p -qp 0 -r 20 video.mkv -y -an
```

I've tried to use `.mkv` and `.mov` and there is not much of a difference, others shows a very poor quality, I've tried to increase `crf`, decrease `b` and `maxrate`.

Any idea of how to reduce the CPU usage? I am already with a terrible video quality (transitions are a mess) and on top of that, I have my computer very slow...

I know that stack already has some answers to it, but (1) none of them solved/helped my issue; (2) they are a little bit old, so, maybe new versions came with new solutions to it...

Comment: You've specified three different ratecontrol methods, all of which are mutually exclusive: drop the `-qp 0` which is for lossless encoding, and will increase CPU use. Pick one between `crf and `b:v`. For a resolution of `2560x1600`, maxrate and bufsize are very low unless your content is visually very simple.

Comment: `-video_size` should come before `-i`. You'll want to limit encoding threads, not decoding, so `-threads` should go after `-i`.

Comment: I've tried to change `-threads` to after `-i` but it didn't change anything...

Comment: Share the command and log of your latest run